# the use of the lock keyword over different threads

Tags: c#, multithreading

I am thinking that when I start my first thread, it should print "one + n" and lock l,then after this, it should start the second thread and print "two + n".

What actually happens, is that when I run the program I get random results, sometimes printing "one + n", other times printing "two + n"

My understanding of this is obviously flawed - why?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
class locked
{
    public long numtochange { get; set; }
    public string threadname { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    public static locked l;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        l = new locked();

        (new Thread(x => { l.threadname = "one"; Print(l); })).Start();


        (new Thread(x => { l.threadname = "two"; Print(l); })).Start();

        Console.ReadLine(); 
    }
    public static void Print(locked l)
    {
        lock (l)
        {
            for (long i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
            {
                l.numtochange = i;
                Console.WriteLine(l.threadname + " " + l.numtochange);
            }
        }    
    }
}
}
```

Comment: You kind of got an answer but without understanding your thinking it is hard to explain your mistake. *Why* do you think the program would print what you predicted?

Answer (score 5):

This part of your code:

```
l.threadname = "one";
```

and the corresponding one with `= "two"` are not locked. Hence they can interleave randomly - sometimes the string `"one"` ends up in `l.threadname` and sometimes it is being overwritten by `"two"`. Then, the first thread that manages to get to the `lock` statement in the `Print` function does its job and the other one waits.

The simplest fix, if you want them to run sequentially, is to wrap both statements with the `lock` keyword, like this:

```
lock (l) { l.threadname = "one"; Print(l); }
```

(`lock` is reentrant so there will be no problem with another `lock` in `Print`).

However if they always run one after another then there is no point in using threads.

Comment: this can be visualized if you print out the thread id `Console.WriteLine(l.threadname + " " + l.numtochange + " " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);`